# Check if master branch have new commits

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

Is where are a better way to understand is where any new commit will be fetched with git fetch when:

```
git fetch origin --dry-run -v 2>&1| grep 'master'| grep 'up to date'
```

And then, if output looks like:

```
= [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
```

I will not need to do actual fetch, and if not - i do a fetch.

I'm using this method right now, but i wonder is where are a better solution?

Also i want to check similar thing for hg - is where are a way to do so?

Comment: Asking whether running command *X* (for some *X*) will do something, and then choosing to run *X* or not based on the answer, is often a poor plan. The answer may *change* by the time you decide to run (or not run) *X*. This is true of both `git fetch` and `hg pull`. You are much better off actually running them, and seeing what happened, because doing a "dry run" first gives you a race condition: someone else, working on the upstream repository, can easily change the answer between "test" and "go".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git fetch --dry-run` to check if remote has new changes to fetch. It will

> show what would be done without making any changes

.

Also you can use `hg incoming` to check if there has changes to fetch.

> Mercurial provides the `hg incoming` command to tell us what changes the
>   `hg pull` command would pull into the repository, without actually
>   pulling the changes in.

Comment: where is no --dry-run option    hg pull: option --dry-run not recognized

Comment: You can use `hg incoming` in mercurial. See `hg help incoming`.

Comment: Yes, @nathan12343 was right, please try to use `hg incoming` instead, it will show if there has changes before really pulling.